# Unknown database type tsvector requested

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, tsvector

so my problem is that i added a column of type tsvector in a table without adding it in the entity class and now when i want to run `doctrine:schema:update --force` it gives me this error

```
Unknown database type tsvector requested, 
Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it.
```

what should i do now, do i have to create a tsvector type in doctrine or delete the tsvector column update the schema with the commande line and then add the tsvector column back ?

Comment: so i think i found the solution here https://gist.github.com/darklow/3129096, the problem is that doctrine dont know the tsvecor type thats why we have to add a class implementing some methods to convert this type from sql to php and verse versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should always register any type the you use and that is not supported by doctrine, thats the most obvious example of registering tsvector type https://gist.github.com/darklow/3129096 and in your config.yml add this:

```
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        tsvector:
            class: myProject\myBundle\Type\tsvectorType
    mapping_types:
        tsvector: tsvector
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not planning to use it with Doctrine you can just add the following to your doctrine config.

```
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    ...
    ...
    types:
        tsvector: string
        hstore: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously doctrine abstraction layer doesn't know such type, so it can't make any use of such typed column, even if column is already defined in database table...

Consider registering new doctrine [custom type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types). There is example of tsvector type implementation https://gist.github.com/darklow/3129096